# Unable to Retrieve Json value from CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I am in need to send Json value as payload which is stored in csv file using CSV config element in Jmeter

But in Jmeter value is not properly updated only bracket is updated in the payload fields

Comment: could you please specify the reason for downvote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing spaces and line brakes from JSON so it will fit at the one line. Also [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) stands for comma-separated-values and [in JSON data is separated by commas](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) as well so it might be the clash there as well.

If you have only one JSON payload which you need to read from the file in the file system you can consider switching to [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.json,,)}
```

[image]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept